# How to set 644 permission on php-fpm log file?

Tags: php-fpm

The FPM log file located in /var/log/php-fpm.log has permissions `rw-------` (600). Other log files have `rw-r--r--`. How can I configure the file permission to 644?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
chmod 644 /var/log/php-fpm.log
```

Comment: Indeed, that works on an existing log file and is persistent across FPM restarts and server reboots. But if the file is being created for the first time (or if I delete it for some reason, say) the default permission on the new file is still 600. Is there any way to ensure 644 like for other programs' log files?

Comment: Why not just create it yourself with `cd /var/log` `sudo touch php-fpm.log` `sudo chown correctUser:correctGroup php-fpm.log` `sudo chmod 644 php-fpm.log`? How often are you deleting it?

Answer (score 0):

Set the logging of PHP-FPM to syslog instead of it's own logging.

; Error log file
; If it's set to "syslog", log is sent to syslogd instead of being written
; in a local file.
; Note: the default prefix is /var
; Default Value: log/php-fpm.log

error_log = syslog

; syslog_facility is used to specify what type of program is logging the
; message. This lets syslogd specify that messages from different facilities
; will be handled differently.
; See syslog(3) for possible values (ex daemon equiv LOG_DAEMON)
; Default Value: daemon

syslog.facility = daemon

; syslog_ident is prepended to every message. If you have multiple FPM
; instances running on the same server, you can change the default value
; which must suit common needs.
; Default Value: php-fpm

syslog.ident = php-fpm